# Sensor for tank fluid measurement

Tags: sensor, distance, sonar

What kind of low cost sensor can be used for a tank fluid level measurement up to about 1m distance, with accuracy of about 5%. Interface to controller can be anything reasonable (SPI, I2C, digital, etc). Some processing is acceptable.

Comment: Have you looked on here before posting? see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/424075/152903

Comment: Ultrasonic sensor is cheap and easy to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sensor For Continuous Water Level Measurement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/424075/sensor-for-continuous-water-level-measurement)